# Ceiling fan stops after a few seconds

Tags: fan

I just installed a ceiling fan on our patio. When turning on the power, the fan starts spinning as I would expect it to. After a few seconds however, the fan seems to be spinning only through inertia and eventually comes to a stop.  It doesn't seem to start again after waiting for a while (at least ten minutes)  Turning the switch off and on again will once more cause the fan to spin up, but it just stops once again shortly thereafter.

The direction switch on the fan doesn't change anything. The same behavior occurs whether the fan is set to spin clockwise or counter-clockwise.

Any ideas on what could be the cause and potential solution?

In case it's helpful, this is a 52" Tilghman fan by Harbor Breeze (#0294981) installed with a separately purchased 48" downrod.

Comment: Do you have a voltage sensor or multimeter you could use to see if power is being constantly supplied? Is there anything special about the switch being used to control the fan?

Comment: @overslacked:  Sure enough, the wiring was not done properly.  After re-wiring things, the fan is now functioning properly.

Comment: this question is showing up unanswered.

Comment: @TJR fixed that.  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a comment on the question, [overslacked](https://diy.stackexchange.com/users/879/overslacked) wrote:

> Do you have a voltage sensor or
>   multimeter you could use to see if
>   power is being constantly supplied? Is
>   there anything special about the
>   switch being used to control the fan?

Turns out these questions implied the actual answer:  The wiring is incorrect.