# What could cause my ceiling fan light to go off after 2 seconds of being on?

Tags: ceiling-fan

The light in my Harbor Breeze ceiling fan stays lit for only 2 seconds. Otherwise the unit works great.  What do I need to do to fix this issue?

Comment: what kind of light bulb is in there? what is the fixtures recommended wattage and what wattage of bulb/bulbs do you have in there? is it a new fan or existing fan? if it was an existing fan did it just start happening? this is a pretty vague description i would need a little more info to help. could be a few things.

Comment: Are you tripping a circuit or just the light is turning off?

Comment: Could be a loose connection, like once the socket or wiring gets warmed up enough the heat expansion might warp something enough to break the circuit.

Comment: possible duplicates, or at least worth reviewing: http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/1511/what-is-the-purpose-of-a-watt-regulator-in-my-ceiling-fan?rq=1 http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/6938/ceiling-fan-stops-after-a-few-seconds?rq=1

Comment: Mine had same issue and it was a weak remote control battery.

Answer (score 2):

The bulb wattage is too high.  Try moving the wattages down a notch and this should alleviate the problem.

Comment: worth reviewing: [What is the purpose of a watt regulator in my ceiling fan?](http://diy.stackexchange.com/q/1511/6742)

Answer (score 1):

The light on my Hampton Bay fan would come on for 2 seconds, then shut off.  After uninstalling the remote receiver the light worked perfectly. I don't have a remote anymore but that's ok.

Comment: So you're suggesting the problem is with the remote receiver unit?

Answer (score 1):

I came here after just having this problem. Mine was a bit sillier: the light bulb I was using has an automatic sensor that shuts the bulb off in the presence of light. You know, to be economic if you leave the light on.